# Start a springboot application from another one

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application (A). This application(A) always starts as the first one. I have to start another SpringBoot application  (B) based on a flag from application A and discontinue running the application A. How to start the second application from the first one?

Comment: What is the exact use case to be achieved by doing so? Also what has been tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the commands through **ProcessBuilder**.

Comment: Although this may answer the question, consider adding more details like code samples, explanation etc. One line answer are in general discouraged and likely to be down voted and / or flagged for closure.